# How to put image to the relevant folder if the percentage is below 50 from Python

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
 # loop over the indexes of the high confidence class labels
                for (i, j) in enumerate(idxs):
                    label1 = mlb.classes_[j]  # Label
                    label2 = "{:.2f}%".format(proba[j] * 100)  # Percentage
                    label3 = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(mlb.classes_[j], proba[j] * 100)  # Label and Percentage

                    # accuracy = label2[0][i] * 100
                    text = cv2.putText(output, label3, (10, (i * 30) + 25),
                                       cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 100, 0), 

                    pat = os.path.split(imagePath)
                    print(pat[0])
                    print(pat[1])

                if label1 == "Looking Straight" and label2 >= str(50):
                    path = "D:/Icorve Project/Learn Neural Networks/Categorical/Looking Straight/{}"
                    print(path.format(pat[1]))
                    cv2.imwrite(path.format(pat[1]), output)

                else:
                    path = "D:/Icorve Project/Learn Neural Networks/Categorical/Looking Away/{}"
```

In here there are three classes. For ex:
     1. Looking Straight

```
for an example if i take Looking straight one the label is printing on on the image saying "Looking straight" : 98.25%  its working perfectly. But i want to put below 50 percentage images to another folder. How to do it ???
Label1 = Class name
label2 = Percentage 
label 3 = Class name + percentage
```

: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
[INFO] classifying image...
examples
data_248000_249000.h5_922.png
D:/Icorve Project/Learn Neural Networks/Categorical/Looking Straight/data_248000_249000.h5_922.png
(531, 413)
(531, 413, 3)
(180, 140, 1)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the first if is inside the for loop.

Then, you could use:

```
proba[j] >= 0.5
```

Instead of

```
label2 >= str(50)
```